On the cursive penmanship
In France, I was taught to write in cursive penmanship from my 6 years old to my 10 years old (alongside vocabulary, grammar, grammatical conjugation and so on). Once I have completed this learning, I did not think of changing my penmanship style because... That was what my maîtresses d'école had always shown to me.
During my PhD, I happened to teach to a few hundred of students at my university through the 3 years and was extremely surprised by two statistics that I did not thoroughly computed, they are only on my presentiment. Please do not hesitate to correct it and add a reference.

More than 80% of students were not using cursive penmanship at all
Nearly every time a student was using penmanship, it was harder to read than printscript.

Another statistic that I noticed is that boys usually use penmanship more often than girls.
That is, during my PhD, I decided to learn printscript and after more than 10 years of my father telling me that my handwriting is illegible, he, for the first time said that I wrote something by hand that he could easily read!
My questions for ELL.SE are:

Why did my teachers never decided to teach another penmanship that cursive and always only focused on cursive if at the end more than 80% of my students did not use it for competitive exams?
Is it specific to France? Does it change for English-speaking countries? Do English students are also always taught to write in cursive manner at young age and what are the reasons behind it?

Wikipedia says that cursive penmanship is generally faster but fastest isn't always best.

This is an interesting subject but the question is not about learning to use English, so it's not a good match for this site.  Handwriting is becoming increasingly irrelevant.

@TimR, thank you for your relevant comment.

There is no standard system of penmanship in the Anglophone world  "Cursive" isn't a well-defined term; there are many handwriting models.  "True" cursive is very rare now (and as its letterforms diverge greatly from the Carolingian letters of printed text, it is very hard for most people to read). But most schools will teach some form of "joined-up"  often based in some way on the italic hand or the Chancery style.  Of course individual teachers will introduce their own handwriting idiosyncracies too.  There is a lot more than just "print" and "cursive".

Oh, those squared notebooks I buy in Fnac! That funny writing! Do they still teach it to children?

I was taught italic handwriting at school in the 1960s. Although I like the style, it didn't seem to suit me, so when it was no longer enforced I deliberately changed to a more cursive style.

French normal school education, AFAIK, was based on a single academic model. In many other countries, the specifics of what must be taught are less well defined. Horace Mann, for example, stressed that schools were obligated to produce useful skills in society, rather than memorizing facts.
